# The branch created in git does not display in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, github

I wanna to switch to another branch I created previously, but when I click switch in eclipse, there is only a master.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "[`Team > Switch To... > Other...`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Checking_out_an_existing_Branch)" does not list your branch, check with

- The Git repositories view if you really cannot find said branch, when you unfold the References or Remotes section.
- command line of that other branch actually exist, with:

  ```
  git branch -avv
  ```

If it does not, see if you find the commit you used before with git reflog.

In both case, you can re-create that branch with

```
git checkout -b newbranch <SHA1>
```

Finally, you can switch back to Eclipse, and it will have that branch for you to chose.